# ffmpeg complex_filter fadeout not working

Tags: ffmpeg

Essensially what I am trying to do is concat a.mp4 with b.mp4, display my set of %c.png overlayed ontop for the entire duration of the video and also show d.png overlayed ontop but only for 1 second and then have it fade out. ALL of this works except that d.png remains overlayed and never fades out:

```
ffmpeg -i ./temp/a.mp4 -i media/b.mp4 -i media/splash/%c.png -i ./temp/d.png -y -filter_complex [0:v]scale=568x320,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];[1:v]scale=568x320,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];[2:v]scale=212:242,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2];[3:v]trim=duration=0.5,fade=t=out:st=0:d=0.5[3:v];[v0][0:a][v1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[bg][a];[bg][v2]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2,format=yuv420p[v];[v][3:v]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2,format=yuv420p[v] -map [v] -map [a] -r 29.97 -vcodec libx264 -s 568x320 -flags +loop -b 400k -bufsize 4M -bt 256k -refs 1 -coder 0 -me_range 16 -subq 4 -partitions +parti4x4+parti8x8+partp8x8 -g 250 -keyint_min 25 -level 30 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qcomp 0.6 -trellis 2 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -acodec aac -strict experimental -ab 80k -ar 48000 -ac 2 -strict experimental -f mp4 -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=90 ./temp/1428723401371.mp4
```

Lord Neckbeard, I know you're out there. I've been reading your stackoverflow posts on fade in/out with complex_filter for a few hours now and nothing I've tried has succeeded. Please Lord, accept the above as my humble offering to you and help me fadeout d.png after 1 second.

Comment: That's quite the tag you have there. Can you show the complete console output from the command? Then I'll try to post an answer tomorrow. A quick look at your lengthy command shows `[3:v]` being used as both the input and output *link labels* for the `trim,fade` filterchain. I'm not sure how `ffmpeg` will deal with that.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard here is my original command and output: http://pastebin.com/QEAvMsHw - I tried changing the output for [3:v] although I got the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ffmpeg -y -i a.mp4 -i b.mp4 -i c_%03d.png -loop 1 -i d.png -filter_complex \
"[0:v]scale=568:-2,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; \
 [1:v]scale=568:-2,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; \
 [2:v]scale=212:-1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2]; \
 [3:v]trim=duration=0.5,fade=t=out:st=0:d=0.5[v3]; \
 [v0][0:a][v1][1:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[bg][a]; \
 [bg][v2]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2[bg2]; \
 [bg2][v3]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2,format=yuv420p[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -preset fast -c:a aac -strict experimental \
-ab 80k -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=90 -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

- Avoid using the same link labels for input and output in each filterchain:

  - Wrong: `[v3]filter0,filter1[v3]`
  - Right: `[v3]filter0,filter1[foo]`
- Adding `-loop 1` as an input option for `d.png` allowed the fade to work as expected. Otherwise it was acting as a single frame instead of a continuous stream. By default `overlay` will loop the last frame of the overlaid input, so that is why it just stayed there. That behavior can be changed with the `eof_action` overlay option.
- By default the [image file demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) will use `-framerate 25` for `c_%03d.png`, so you may want to add this as an input option with an appropriate value to change the frame rate and therefore the duration of particular input.
- Use the x264 presets instead of listing a legion of encoding options. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264 Encoding Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).
- Not all players will pay attention to the video stream rotation metadata.

Answer (score 0):

Overlay filter has a setting for "repeatlast", it is set by default to be ON.  set repeatlast=0 in your overlay filterchain and the main video will then be seen.  Sorry I am a couple years too late, hopefully this answer will still help someone.